# CMS blocks disappeared after 1.9.2.2 update

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, static-block, ce-1.9.2.2

Last night my backend was auto updated to 1.9.2.2 release.
Today all my **static block on CMS pages** have disappeared.
They wereconfigured for all store views and I tried each of the views and they are not showing up.
However, I also use **static blocks on category** pages, but that is showing up fine.
Anyone else experiencing this problem? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: After some investigation, it boiled down to this:  
I was including static blocks using    
`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="made_in_the_usa_block"}}`    
But it seems now I need to do this    
`{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="93"}}`    
to make the block show up - why is that?

Comment: Looking in Chrome dev tool, the div I used to wrap the (old way) block are still there, but the content of the block is totally missing.  
Curious why the {{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_name"}} would just stop working.

Comment: Same issue here but I'm trying to make the following block work: `{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/list.phtml"}}
`

Comment: @francis-kim, just wondering if you got that block working, and how? I have a very similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @wclear whitelist the blocks - check the answer.

Comment: Thank you @francis-kim, it was just a bit confusing that the type attribute was what needed to be included as the block name on the block permissions screen. All working now!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My understanding is that **CE 1.9.2.2** includes all the changes from the [**recent-patch**](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) [**SUPEE-6788**](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788), one of which was restrict the blocks that can be used in CMS blocks, pages, emails (etc...) by default.

Fortunately you can *whitelist* additional blocks through the admin under `System > Permissions > (Blocks | Variables)`

Comment: Yup! That would be it. Thanks for the tip.  
Fortunately I have about a dozen of static block not hundreds... Now I need to find the correct "name" for them.   
How **DO** I find the correct name, it's so cryptic.  
Magento sure don;t make life easy for me.

Comment: Use the [additional N98-MageRun commands](https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons) created by @peter-jaap-blaakmeer for the excellent N98-MageRun Magento command-line tool.

**Find non-whitelisted vars/blocks to be compatible with SUPEE-6788 and Magento 1.9.2.2**

$ n98-magerun dev:template-vars [--addblocks[="true|false"]] [--addvariables[="true|false"]]

Comment: What about widgets? Like this: {{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

Answer (score 20):

I used below method:

1. `System > Permissions > Blocks`
2. Add New Block
3. Block Name: `cms/block`
4. Is Allowed : Yes

This seems to have done the trick for me.

Comment: @Francis Kim  you need to add Block Name: catalog/navigation using the same method as above to get your block to show.

Answer (score 1):

Digging the database these days I found a typo in permission_block table. catalog/nagivation value as block_name must be catalog/navigation. Check your installations for this error.