# Calling a Static-Block in a CMS-Page is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I want to call a Static-block (Identifier* name is`static-block-to-use-in-cms-page` in a CMS Page.

In CMS-Page's Content (Left Navigation Tab) field I called that static block by using this code

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="static-block-to-use-in-cms-page"}}.
```

Comment: Might be related to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88117/cms-blocks-disappeared-after-1-9-2-2-update

Comment: Thanks to you too. Although by seeing that question I thought irrelevant to my problem first, later I saw there also have useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to set a permission for cms/block.
In this case, go to `Sytem > Permissions > Blocks`

Now click on `Add New Block` and write `cms/block` on Block Name*
And set Yes from Is Allowed.