# Add block from custom module to CMS page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, cms, phtml

I created a module with a simple phtml file.
Then i created a CMS page, and in the design tab a added this code:

```
<reference name="content">
 <block type="oproduct_export/infoshow" name="block"  template="oproduct_export/export.phtml" />
 </reference>
```

and also this:

```
{{block type="oproduct_export/infoshow " name="custom" template="oproduct_export/export.phtml"}}
```

**export.phtml** it's in the right place.
What it's the most courious thing, it's because i have the same thing on my local, and everything works fine, and my phtml appears in the cms page, but when I put all of the code on the server, the phtml doesn't appears.

I also created another modules and for any custom modules with custom phtml that I created, is not  working on the server.
If I add an existent magento block in my cms page, this phtml works fine and it appears on the cms page.

Does anyone know where it's my problem?

Comment: block added to whiltelist?

Comment: i am not sure what this means

Comment: refer this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88124/20064

Comment: you have a blank space in your block type `type="oproduct_export/infoshow "`. Make sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added  my block to whitelist but still i have some err : Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='....)

I solve my problem by add **core/template** in stand of **oproduct_export/infoshow** for `block type`

**OLD VERSION**

```
<reference name="content">
 <block type="oproduct_export/infoshow" name="block"  template="oproduct_export/export.phtml" />
 </reference>
```

**NEW VERSION**

```
<reference name="content">
 <block type="core/template" name="block"  template="oproduct_export/export.phtml" />
 </reference>
```

and then i change all my function from block into helper.
To access the functions in the phtml i use this:

```
Mage::helper('yournamespace_module')->function();
```

Answer (score 6):

As Piyush said it's likely you need to whitelist your block type.

Navigate to `System > Permissions > (Blocks | Variables)` and whitelist your block type.

Clear caches and see if it now works.

Comment: so i need to add only the block name in both blocks and variable? in my case :oproduct_export/infoshow ?

Comment: Only in blocks.

Comment: Hmm it could be a code issue, I don't know much PHP so I can't help with that sorry.

Comment: Try removing the : so your block name reads `oproduct_export/infoshow`. Also try removing the space in your block `type`.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora How can i add feedback from into all pages including homepage, my contact form : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0    how can i add to my all pages?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the permission of your newly created block :-This has been since the release of patch SUPEE-6788.

```
System > Permissions >> Blocks
```

Then add your newly created '`oproduct_export/infoshow`' block there.

Answer (score 1):

piyush means goto admin panel . system>permissions>block and add your block there.

also when you encounter things like this you should 
go to **var/log/system.log** or **var/log/exception.log** and see if theres an error message.